# Playing audio files in unsupported codecs through <audio> tag

Tags: javascript, audio, electron, html5-audio, chromium

I've an Electron app where I need to allow the user to play audio files that are in unsupported codecs like CAF/AMR/etc. and also let them control playback (play/pause, seek etc.).

The `<audio>` tag in Chromium/Electron doesn't natively support this.

How can I add support for it? I found https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js but it doesn't seem to do it.

Since it's an Electron app, I can use ffmpeg but I'm not sure how to use it to add support for codecs in the native `<audio>` tag.

Comment: Even if you use native modules, you won't be able to add support for those unsupported codecs in `audio` tag. You will have to modify the core Chromium source code that Electron uses to add support in the `audio` tag

Answer (score 0):

Howler's codec support is reliant on browser support, so if you use [a browser which doesn't support the codec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_audio#Supported_audio_coding_formats), howler.js won't support it either.

It looks like there isn't one plugin which will support all the formats you want, so your only option is to install a javascript plugin for each of the file formats you wish to use. For example, [here's an AMR player](https://github.com/alex374/amr-player).

For stranger audio formats like Apple's CAF, you might need to convert those files on your server and serve the user a more widely supported format.